# One hot encoding on protein sequence in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzjZC.png)

I need to take squences as training data and output column as label. but before I have to apply one hot encoding on the sequences,as you can see sequences varies in length Please suggest me how to apply one-hot encoding on all amino acids to have different integer values assigned

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from numpy import array

# define example
values = array(data)
print(values)
# integer encode
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(values)
print(integer_encoded)

Comment: and second code I used was

df= pd.read_csv('C:/Users/alpha/Desktop/DATASET2.csv',names=('X1','Y'),delimiter=',')
X=df.iloc[:,0].values
Y=df.iloc[:,1:2].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()  # Encode labels with value between 0 and n_classes-1.
X[ : , 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[ : , 0]) # All the rows and first columns

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

labelencoder_Y = LabelEncoder()
Y =  labelencoder_Y.fit_transform(Y)

Comment: Please do **not** post code in the comments - it is literally unreadable! The code should be part of your question in the first place, so please **edit & update** your question accordingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one else can determine the best way to bin your data set. That's a decision that can only be made by someone who has a good understanding of the objective and the dataset. ϕ(x) —your feature vector— is always very specific to your data.

For example if you had DNA you might have features for whether a certain codon is present, or bins for the quantity of Adenine etc., this is highly subjective and even with a good understanding tuning is a non-trivial task.

You have to be very careful because you might create biases in your data for certain classes to be of a certain length, quantity of certain amino acids etc. that are not truly representative of what you are classifying for if you generate the feature vector incorrectly. This could lead to testing and training error rates that are deceptive and produce incorrect conclusions.

Honesty, if you are in university, I would recommend soliciting someone in a computer science department or other analog to help contribute to your project. While it might seem tempting to use the pre-baked sklearn encoding it is not a good solution for your case. It is very likely you will have outlier cases in terms of sequence length due to limited quantity of data, and attempting to turn each character into it's own feature will cause poor performance with regards to fitting.

As for actually reading your data into python, it's a csv so you could parse it by hand with an open() and a split(',') or you could use some of the popular libraries for parsing csv formats. YMMV